# reactJS material UI Icon button to upload file

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to know how can I open the directory to upload a file using an IconButton?

```
<IconButton 
  iconClassName="fa fa-plus-square" 
  onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()} 
  type='file'
/>
```

using the code below shows the icon button and another button for the upload file

```
<IconButton iconClassName="fa fa-plus-square" onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
    <input type="file type='file'>
</IconButton>
```

Answer (score 13):

I think the standard way from material ui examples:

```
 <input accept="image/*" className={classes.input} id="icon-button-file" type="file" />
  <label htmlFor="icon-button-file">
    <IconButton color="primary" className={classes.button} component="span">
      <PhotoCamera />
    </IconButton>
  </label>
```

Comment: To use the file on upload, you can add `onChange={(event) => { const files = event.target.files; ... }}` to the input element.

Comment: doesn't work, it still shows two buttons

Answer (score 9):

A few things:

1. You don't need `type='file'` on the IconButton, just on the input
2. IconButton does not expect its children to be anything other than an SVGIcon, so I recommend that you use a regular button
3. I wouldn't call stopPropagation in this case
4. You have a typo in your type prop for the input. You have `type="file type='file'`. It should just be `type="file"`

So, putting that all together:

```
<FlatButton label="Choose file" labelPosition="before">
  <input type="file" style={styles.exampleImageInput} />
</FlatButton>
```

If you still want it to be an icon rather than a button, I suspect you can do something with `<input>` or add it as the children to FlatButton with no label.

Comment: Beware:  Your hidden file input might not take up the full height/width of your button container and not do anything when the button is clicked outside of the file input.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve the same with `IconButton` using the following code:

```
<IconButton onClick={() => this.fileUpload.click()}>
   <FontIcon className="material-icons" >
       add_a_photo
   </FontIcon>
  </IconButton>
<input type="file" ref={(fileUpload) => {
                    this.fileUpload = fileUpload;
                  }}
  style={{ visibility: 'hidden'}} onChange={this.groupImgUpload} />
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use input element and IconButton to create file upload functionality in the following way

```
<StyledTableCell className={classes.cellMarginBottom}>
    <input
        onChange={handleColumnChange}
        type={'file'}
        name={'attachments'}
        id={rowIndex}
        multiple
        hidden
    />
    <label htmlFor={rowIndex}>
        <IconButton size='small' component="span">
            <AttachFileIcon className={classes.attachIcon}/>
        </IconButton>
    </label>
</StyledTableCell>


const handleColumnChange = useCallback(event => {
    const name = event.currentTarget.name || event.target.name
    const value = event.currentTarget.value || event.target.value
    if (name === 'attachments') {
        const filesKeys = Object.keys(event.target.files)
        const rowIndex = event.target.id
        let files = []

        for (const key in filesKeys) {
            if (event.target.files[key]) {
                files = files.concat(event.target.files[key])
            }
        }
        onAttachChange({
            [name]: row.attachments.concat(files),
            rowIndex: rowIndex
        })
    }
})
```