# Open "choose file" dialog box on onclick of Raised Button Material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a Floating button (material ui) in my react project. I want to open "choose file" dialoge box whenever I click it. I am not getting any solution to do that. I tried doing this but didn't work. and  I don't want to use jquery.

```
</div>
            <input id="myInput" type="file" style="visibility:hidden" />
            <FloatingActionButton className="floatingButton" backgroundColor='#293C8E' onClick ="$('#myInput').click();">
                <ContentAdd />
            </FloatingActionButton>
        </div>
```

Can someone please tell me what exactly I need to do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Basic example (does not include what to do with selected file):

```
  <div>
    <input id="myInput" type="file" ref={(ref) => this.upload = ref} style={{ display: 'none' }} />
    <FloatingActionButton
      className="floatingButton"
      backgroundColor='#293C8E'
      onClick={(e) => this.upload.click() }
      >
      <ContentAdd />
    </FloatingActionButton>
  </div>
```

So, your FloatingActionButton's onClick handler manually fires the click() handler of a hidden file upload control (input type="file"). A reference to the hidden upload control is obtained by putting a ref callback on it and storing that reference in "this.upload" (could also use DOM or jQuery to do that, but ref is preferred in React)

here is a working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/432yz8qg/58/

Answer (score 2):

You can do the trick with the help of `<label/>` tag:

```
<label htmlFor='myInput'>
  <input id="myInput" type="file" style={{visibility: 'hidden'}} />
  <FloatingActionButton
    className="floatingButton"
    backgroundColor='#293C8E'
   >
    <ContentAdd />
   </FloatingActionButton>
</label>
```

Comment: When using the above code you have given, dialogue box is not getting opened when I click the button. why?

Comment: What should i include in onClick method of floating button?

Comment: You shouldn't set any event handlers there. Label tag focuses the input  that is referenced in `for` (or in case of jsx `htmlFor`) attribute input when it's clicked. By setting `onClick` you will override this behaviour.

Comment: So then why the dialogue box is not getting opened as expected when I pasted your code?

Comment: Show `<ContentAdd/>` component please.

Comment: import ContentAdd from 'material-ui/svg-icons/content/add';

Comment: It is just an icon imported

Comment: Ah, ok. I'll try to reproduce the situation and get back to you in some time.

Comment: Okay. That would be a great help. Thanks

Comment: Did you figure out a way?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem in a more React way than Jeff solution though my solution imply the use of multiple CSS rules.

I used a FlatButton with the props containerElement set to "label" :

```js
const { FlatButton, SvgIcon, MuiThemeProvider, getMuiTheme } = MaterialUI;

class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const buttonStyle = {
       minWidth: '56px',
       width: '56px',
       minHeight: '56px',
       height: '56px',
       borderRadius: '28px',
     };
  
    return (
      <div>
        <FlatButton
          containerElement="label"
          backgroundColor='#293C8E'
          style={buttonStyle}
          >
          <input type="file" style={{ display: 'none' }} />
        </FlatButton>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const App = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme() }>
    <Example />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.2.1/dist/react-with-addons.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.2.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/nathanmarks/3f5196f5973e3ff7807f2bab4e603a37/raw/f409f3bf5902c211b358a3ebe7b6cd366da551e8/mui-umd.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

More details here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36262984/2590861